# fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, aws-codecommit

I am not able to push any changes from my local to codecommit and I am getting below error. I can clone, pull from the repo but while pushing I am facing the issue.
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: 403 means "forbidden", access denied. Figure out what is required to gain access. This is usually a matter of passwords and/or tokens, and has to do with HTTPS authentication (since you're using an HTTPS URL). This has nothing to do with Git itself unless you should be telling Git to use something other than HTTPS (in which case, just do that).

Comment: I get this same error when trying to eb deploy (which pushed to codecommit behind the scenes I believe). However, if I delete the "git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" entry from my keyChain, it works. Have to delete it every single time I deploy code and it's maddening.

Answer (score 1):

Check the IAM policies that attached to your user. You probably don't have "codecommit: GitPush" rights.